# Identification: Anime(?) taking place on floating islands with tall, narrow airships

Tags: story-identification, anime

Let me start by saying, I remember *very* little of this anime. It may not even have been an anime, I'm not sure. I think I saw one episode of it in the early-to-mid-00s and for some reason got reminded of it today.

What sticks out most to my mind is the very tall, skinny airships with windows/cockpits at the top, used by who I *think* may have been the antagonists, but may have been some kind of neutral group. Thinking back on it now, they remind me of much bigger versions of B-wings from Star Wars, only without the wings on the sides, if that makes sense to anyone?

The protagonist, I believe, lived on a small floating island. I'm not sure of any further details, I'm afraid--I remember that it reminded me a bit of Skies of Arcadia, but I think anything with a world of floating islands and airships would remind me of that.

Comment: Was the protagonist male or female? An adult or a child? Do you recall their hair colour?

Comment: @LogicDictates Unfortunately, it was the worldbuilding that stuck in my mind, not the characters. ...Though thinking on it, I want to say young adult or thereabouts? Probably male, but that's more a guess, based on how it felt like a shounen or seinen anime, which usually have male protagonists.

Comment: Were there more than one floating islands? If so this might be Skyland, a show I asked about myself some time ago.

Comment: @Nu'Daq Yes, I believe the entire world was floating islands. Something else I saw also pointed me in the direction of Skyland, let me look into that....

Comment: @Otis It has the same answer, but I certainly wouldn't have recogised that it was the same as what I was looking for from seeing that.

Comment: @Hearth, no problem. It's the policy for story ID questions to link posts with the same answer, as this helps future searchers to locate and verify answers. (Each question usually highlights different details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Skyland](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457541/)*** (2005–2007) seems like a strong contender.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyland):

> *Skyland* (full French title: "Skyland, Le Nouveau Monde", or "Skyland, The New World"), is a CGI animated series developed in France in partnership with Canada and Luxembourg for television channels France 2 in France, Teletoon in Canada, Nicktoons in the United States, ABC in Australia and CITV in the United Kingdom.[3](https://youtu.be/DaCxm6jENKc?t=838) The show is a co-production between Paris's Method Films and Toronto's 9 Story Entertainment.

> Prior to the beginning of the story, in the 23rd century, the Earth has shattered into billions of pieces which orbit around a central core. In this new world, named Skyland, an evolved form of human has appeared: Seijins, who absorb energy from sunlight and use it to fuel special abilities such as telekinesis, telepathy, mental control, astral projection, energy balls or blasts, and electric rays.
>
> The Skyland is ruled by the Sphere: an organization which controls the water supplies, and maintains its power by Guardians, Seijins indoctrinated and trained from childhood. This dictatorship is fought by pirates. After the capture of their mother by the Sphere, protagonists Mahad and Lena, a young Seijin still learning to control her powers, are rescued by a group of pirates, and join the pirate rebellion.

- Animated.
- About the right age.
- Floating islands.
- Tall, skinny airships with windowed cockpits near the top.

You can view some of the airships at around the 13:58 mark in the video below.

Comment: That sounds *really* familiar, and after seeing the airship around 11 minutes into the video, this is definitely what I remembered! Though I remembered the airships being bigger than that, but perhaps I had it mixed up with something else. *definitely* not an anime though, don't know why I was thinking that.

Comment: I'm surprised you were able to come up with this on so little information! The people here sure know their stuff--or at least you and the person who answered my last question do. Thanks, this was bugging me that I didn't know what it was!